# PHP Date 4 Weeks Ago

Tags: php, datetime, unix-timestamp, dst

I have the following code which outputs `20191027` as a result.

If I amend the 2nd line (i.e. set timezone to Auckland), it gives me the result `20191028`. Why is this?

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
#date_default_timezone_set("Pacific/Auckland");

$date_format =  'Ymd';

$day = "Sunday 4 week ago";
$start_of_the_week = strtotime($day);

$next_day = $start_of_the_week + (60 * 60 * 24 * 1);
$next_day = date($date_format, $next_day);

echo $next_day;
```

Check 2 outputs:

- https://3v4l.org/A7ppT (20191027)
- https://3v4l.org/Mfto3 (20191028)

Comment: check strtotime here (1572217200) : https://www.tools4noobs.com/online_tools/unix_timestamp_to_datetime/

Comment: In a nutshell, it comes up with a timestamp at which point in time it's already the 28th down under, but still the 27th in London…

Comment: @deceze Thanks for this. How should I amend `Sunday 4 week ago` so it pulls in `20191028` without having to specify a new time zone?

Comment: By its very nature it's going to depend on timezones one way or the other. The timestamp returned by `strtotime` is accurate to the second, but you basically just want "the day". You can't have a UNIX timestamp of just "a day". That's a bit of a conflict. Would you at least say that you want "Sunday" *in your configured timezone*? So, if you set "Auckland", you get "Sunday 00:00 Auckland time"? Otherwise I'd probably rather fall back on manual calculation than relying on `strtotime` automagic.

Comment: It gets weirder... if you `echo date($date_format, $start_of_the_week)` it comes up as `2019-10-27 00:00:00` in both cases... but then when you add 24 hours to the value you get either `2019-10-27 23:00:00` (London) or `2019-10-28 00:00:00` (Auckland) https://3v4l.org/443me

Comment: @NIck Exactly! I was trying this and getting super frustrated with it. I don't know if it's because that's when the clocks fall back.

Comment: @Nick Yes, DST! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Summer_Time Which is why you never add "a day" with `60 * 60 * 24`.

Comment: Dang it. What's the best approach when adding a day, would you say? Thanks for your help here.

Comment: Well, first of all: https://youtu.be/-5wpm-gesOY. Secondly, perhaps look into a library like Carbon which makes PHP date handling slightly more sane. PHP's date primitives are… rather primitive. Other languages have objects for *dates*, PHP only has *`DateTime`* which has the accurate-to-the-second problem when you just want a date. Thirdly, it's been a while since I've had to wrangle this issue in PHP, so don't have a great solution off the top of my head.

Comment: Ah the old DST strikes again. Talk about bad timing!

Comment: Use a Datetime object and add one day

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `Europe/London` timezone...

> DST ended on Sun 27-Oct-2019 at 02:00:00 A.M. when local clocks were
>   set backward 1 hour

Keep in mind that that `strtotime` operates on unix timestamps where there is no concept of DST but the `date` function adjusts the unix timestamp to local timezone when formatting it. So:

```
$start_of_the_week = strtotime("Sunday 4 week ago"); // $start_of_the_week is some unix timestamp
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $start_of_the_week);        // 2019-10-27 00:00:00 Europe/London time

$next_day = $start_of_the_week + (60 * 60 * 24 * 1); // you're adding 24 hours to a unix timestamp
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $next_day);                 // 2019-10-27 23:00:00 Europe/London time
```

And `2019-10-27 23:00:00` is still a Sunday. The solution is to add days instead of hours:

```
$next_day = strtotime("+1 day", $start_of_the_week); // 2019-10-28 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, the issue is with `Europe/London` finishing daylight savings time on that day 4 weeks ago, so adding 24 hours to that time only took you forward by 23 hours. You can avoid issues like this by using `DateTime` objects and only working with days:

```
$date_format =  'Y-m-d H:i:s';
$day = "Sunday 4 week ago";

date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
$date = new DateTime($day);
$date->modify('+1 day');
echo $date->format($date_format) . "\n";

date_default_timezone_set("Pacific/Auckland");
$date = new DateTime($day);
$date->modify('+1 day');
echo $date->format($date_format) . "\n";
```

Output:

```
2019-10-28 00:00:00
2019-10-28 00:00:00
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/rv8PU)

You can specify the timezone directly to the `DateTime` constructor too:

```
$date_format =  'Y-m-d H:i:s';
$day = "Sunday 4 week ago";

$date = new DateTime($day, new DateTimeZone("Europe/London"));
$date->modify('+1 day');
echo $date->format($date_format) . "\n";

$date = new DateTime($day, new DateTimeZone("Pacific/Auckland"));
$date->modify('+1 day');
echo $date->format($date_format) . "\n";
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/tHZUe)

Answer (score 0):

there is a difference between every time zone.

For Example

"India is 10 hours and 30 minutes ahead of Washington, DC, USA". If the echo the time of these time zones, it would end in giving different results.

In your case "Auckland, New Zealand is 13 hours ahead of London, UK", hence it is giving different O/P's

Hope this resolves your answer to the question :)

Comment: I guess the main thing I don't understand is when I'm saying "Sunday, 4 weeks ago" - then isn't that universally going to be `20191028`? Is there a better way of doing that?

Comment: There's just a day's difference between `20191027` and `20191028` it will still go to check under the timezone, doing calculations, you'll end up the same result. I would suggest to implement a manual method than relying on inbuilt functions.